# No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

I apologize in advance for my English. I'm new to programming. There is a problem with stored procedures in PostgreSQL.
I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
   Id serial,
   idGroup INTEGER,
   firstname VARCHAR(45),
   lastname VARCHAR(45)
)
```

I want to create a procedure that adds a new user.
The procedure itself has been created, but I can't add a new user to it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usernew
(
    c_Id INOUT INTEGER,
    c_idGroup INTEGER,
    c_firstname VARCHAR(45),
    c_lastname VARCHAR(45)
)

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
$$

BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO public.user (idGroup, firstname, lastname) values
     (c_idGroup,
          c_firstname,
          c_lastname
     ) RETURNING Id INTO c_Id;
END
$$;

call usernew(1, 'poppy', 'jacobs')
```

The following error occurs:

```
ERROR:  procedure usernew(integer, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: call usernew(1, 'poppy', 'jacobs')
             ^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 

SQL state: 42883
Character: 6
```

I tried to solve the problem by using CAST (.. AS ...), but it did not help.

Help me please. Thank you in advance for your cooperation!

Comment: you have 4 parameneters so you need to call with 4 parameters `call "usernew"(1, 1,'poppy', 'jacobs')` see https://dbfiddle.uk/dV1lIVal

Comment: You are sending 3 parameter where its expecting 4, if cId is auto generated then remove that from store procedure. Currently its considering 'poppy' as value of c_idGroup's value,  which expecting int and getting varchar.

Comment: Sorry, but I have a new error:  "column "idgroup" of relation "user" does not exist", but but the column already exists. Or am I missing something :(

Comment: In addition, Postgresql automatically lowercase ALL use of column and table names unless they are put in double quotes.  Your `idGroup` got turned into `idgroup` and they are not the same identifier.  Use double quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in the registry. Even if we remove idgroup, the error appears with respect to firstname

Comment: The issue may not be related to the actual code at all, but to your table name. `user` is a Postgres and SQL Standard [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and is used improperly. Try changing your table name. You could use `"User"` or even `users` or  (perhaps better) `app_users`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a simple SQL *function* rather than a procedure. Here it is.

```sql
CREATE or replace function usernew(c_idGroup INTEGER, c_firstname text, c_lastname text)
returns integer LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  INSERT INTO public.user (idGroup, firstname, lastname)
  VALUES (c_idGroup, c_firstname, c_lastname)
  RETURNING id;
$$;
```

Use it like this

```sql
SELECT usernew (1, 'poppy', 'jacobs');
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/31PUUWZyWf7eJJ3vTuv4g8/2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the error remains.
At first I entered your code, but I got the following error: 
ERROR:  Failing row contains (null, 1, poppy, jacobs).null value in column "id" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint 

ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (null, 1, poppy, jacobs).
Context: SQL function "usernew" statement 1
Then I corrected a little and gave the old error again. I don't understand what's the matter

Comment: Well, there is not much to be corrected. Are you sure that column `id` of table `user` is of type `serial`?

Comment: It all seems to work fine. Pls. see the demo in the updated answer

Comment: @newbloom That error messages comes from a constraint that is not part of the DDL that you published in your question. There is no NOT NULL constraint nor primary key in your table. Besides that, the column "id" is a serial and creates a new value by default.